# Append the new url with old Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.4, redirect

I am new to laravel 5.4
My problem is i have to append the new url with existing one.

For example if browser has url "http://localhost/manager/public/file/5" then on click of button the new url should be http://localhost/manager/public/file/5/employee.

I have achieved this with "Route::get('/file/{bId}/employee','EmployeeController@som');"
and it works fine if i manually hit url in browser.

Problem is I am using url('employee') which generates url "http://localhost/manager/public/employee".

Comment: can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `/employee`, the `/` is important

```
url('/employee')
```